# How to Get BandedGridView cell value

Tags: c#, devexpress

I want to loop into every column and row of a BandedGridView and get the cell value, to set some conditions like

```
if (value>70)
     BandedGridView.cell.foreColor = Color.Green;
```

Something like that it's just an example because i don't know how to do it, i hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you need to set cell forecolor equals to `Color.Green` if cell value is greater than 70. To achieve this you need to handle `RowCellStyle` event of `BandedGridView` and in that handler method you can check cell value and if cell value is greater than 70 then you can set appreance of forecolor for that cell.

```
private void BandedGridView1_RowCellStyle(object sender,DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowCellStyleEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CellValue > 70)
    {
       e.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    } 

}
```

Comment: Is what i want, but now i have another problem, the event doesn't fire up

Comment: have you just copied code and past in your solution ? or you created event handler by double click on event section from property panel ?

Comment: I create the event from property panel for the bandedgridview

Comment: It's always fire if gridview has data to display.

Comment: Maybe is the way i fill the gridview, y fill it from a data table when a button get clicked, i try too to fire the evente manually but doesn't happen

Comment: @mch505 Will back to you why it's not firing event. Right now no access of VS.

Comment: @mch505 I checked bandedgridview's RowCellStyle Event and it's working perfectly.